# Derivative of $x^a$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to calculate the derivative of function $f$ such, that:
$f(x)=x^a$, where $x>0$ and $a\in \Bbb R$.

Do you know any formula for $(x+h)^a$?

Comment: How was $x^a$ defined?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know. What are the possibilities?

Comment: Among the sensible possibilities, only $x^a = \exp(a\cdot \log x)$ comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $a$ an integer one can prove that $f'(x)=ax^{a-1}$ by induction. In the general case we can use the chain rule:
$$
f(x)=e^{a\log x}
$$
so
$$
f'(x)=e^{a\log x}\cdot a\cdot \frac{1}{x}=ax^{a-1}
$$
Of course $f$ is defined only for $x>0$ if $a$ is not supposed to be an integer, but an arbitrary real number.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can show it very easily what it is starting from the definition. Let's make the example when $a$ is an integer (as a hint) (you know what the definition of the derivative is?).
$$
f'(y)=\lim_{x\to y} \frac{x^a-y^a}{x-y}=\frac{(x-y)(x^{a-1}+ax^{a-2}+...)}{x-y}=ax^{a-1}
$$
I skipped some steps, but I think you can try to reproduce them as an exercise. If is not clear let us know, and we can help you more.

Comment: if a is an integer, solution is much easier. I just don't know exactly what does $x^a$ mean.

Comment: Check this link http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Power_(Algebra) it contains interesting insight in how you can define powers of numbers...

Comment: And even more ;-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation have fun reading...

Comment: How does this work out in full, exactly?  What happens to $(x^{a - 1} + ax^{a - 2} + . . . $ for non-integral $a$?  I feel I should know/have seen this, but can't remember.  Maybe I should check the wiki pages . . .

Comment: When a is not an integer the method I outlined is not working anymore, since you cannot factor $x-y$ anymore. When $a$ is real you have to distinguish between rational numbers and non-rational numbers. That makes again a difference. You can define (as was mentioned in a comment before) the power as $f(x)=e^{a\ln x}$. To derivate this you must know how to derivate composite functions and how to derivate the exponential and the logarithm... How to show the derivate is strongly dependent from the way you define your function.

Comment: Right, as in logarithmic differentiation . . . thanks for clarifying.  Regards.

Comment: @RobertLewis Yep. Exactly. And for that check the answer from egreg below or from Robert.

Answer (score 2):

Try logarithmic differentiation:  if $f(x) = x^a$, then $\ln f(x) = a \ln x$, whence
$(1 / f(x)) f'(x) = a / x$.  Thus $f'(x) = af(x) / x = ax^a /x = ax^{a - 1}$, just as if $a$ were an integer.

I can't, off the top of my head, quote a formula for $(x + h)^a$, but I'm pretty sure something along those lines is known.  Might be a challenge to do the algebra required in computing the derivative, to wit $((x + h)^a - x^a) / h$, when $a$ is not a postivie integer.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***